# Gson GraphAdapter and RuntimeAdapter

Tags: java, serialization, gson

my first question, so let me know if I'm missing something =)

I've been working on a project, which pipeline was passed to me, and is based on Gson encoding/decoding to pass messages through modules.

At some point I needed to serialize polymorphic classes and make sure I decoded them correctly, and I found [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java), which works perfectly.

The concrete case was something like this:

```
public class Tree {
  Node root;
}

public class Node {
  List<Node> nodeChildren;
}

public class Token extends Node {}
```

Basically a `Tree` has a root, which can be either a `Node` or `Token`, and the nodes in the tree can either be `Nodes` or actual `Tokens`.

The following code would do the job when performing Gson en/decoding:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Node> nodeAdapter = new RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Node>(Node.class);
nodeAdapter.registerSubtype(Token.class);
nodeAdapter.registerSubtype(Node.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().(..).registerTypeAdapterFactory(nodeAdapter).create();
```

Then, more recently, I found out that I needed circular references in the leaf `Tokens` of my `Trees`. Turns out Gson doesn't support cycles, but there's also an adaptor for that: [GraphAdapterBuilder](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java). It seemed to perform exactly what I wanted, according to the test classes. The problem is that I can't find a way to combine them. I thought something like this would do it:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Node> nodeAdapter = new RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Node>(Node.class);
nodeAdapter.registerSubtype(Token.class);
nodeAdapter.registerSubtype(Node.class);
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().(..).registerTypeAdapterFactory(nodeAdapter);
GraphAdapterBuilder graphBuilder = new GraphAdapterBuilder();
graphBuilder.addType(Token.class);
graphBuilder.registerOn(builder);
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "0x2"` when decoding. The same happens if I only register the `RuntimeFactory` after calling `registerOn(builder)`. This means I'm delegating on the `RuntimeFactory` before the `GraphBuilder` consumes the `0x?` ids.

If I completely remove the `RuntimeFactory`, based in the assumption that the Graph would suffice the runtime object creation, I get another exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING` when decoding, which probably means I'm not delegating on the `GraphBuilder` to consume the `0x?` id as well.

I pretty much tried every combination of registrations and builder/adapters, always with different results except the expected behavior. Other exceptions from other combinations include `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected recursive call to read() for 0x2` and `JsonParseException: cannot deserialize Token because it does not define a field named type` (this one I noticed that the `RuntimeFactory` would only be applied in the recursive `Tokens` found by the `GraphBuilder`, but not in other instances of `Token` I had.

Now, what I expected from this mix was something like: Gson finds `Token` and delegates to `GraphFactory` which adds the id `0x?` and then delegates to the `RuntimeFactory` that adds the `type` and then delegates to Gson again for the rest of the fields. But it seems I can't get the factories right to perform this. Am I missing something, or the only way to accopmlish this is to mix both into the same Factory myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this?

Comment: GraphAdapterBuilder has a simple (too simple?) design that uses artificial keys for the linking of objects. This kind of solution has technical aspects in mind. You loose readability and compatibility and the non-compatibility is what you are experiencing.